# Milchig / Fleishig Arrangement

Tags: meat-and-milk, appliances, architecture-design

When designating which sink in a kitchen is Milchig and which is Fleishig, is there any preferred method for which should side should be which. (Eg left meat and right milk, or vice versa)? What about for utensils?

Comment: Note incidentally that a kosher kitchen does not need separate sinks for dairy and meat, contrary to some people's apparent belief. (Until fairly recently it was highly unusual to have more than one sink in a kitchen, even a kosher kitchen.) (I don't mean to imply that the questioner here is misinformed; I'm merely informing anyone interested.)

Comment: Many question the whole idea of having one sink divided into two, because if cham miktzaso cham kulo (if part of an object is hot, the whole piece is hot), when one pours hot water (over 110 F) onto the Fleishig side, the whole sink becomes fleishig, and then when one pours hot water over the milchig, it absorbs from the milk side, and causes Basar and Chalav.

Comment: @JoeShmoe- that is not correct.  Unless you have a heat source in your sink, iruy will only affect the specific places you poured onto.

Comment: @msh210 How so (how would it work)?

Comment: @yydl, AFAIK (and this is how I grew up) you don't put dishes on the floor of the sink, putting them on a drainboard/dishrack/whatever it's called instead (separate racks for dairy and for meat), and don't let hot water rise to the level of the dishes in the sink, but CYLOR.

Comment: I have heard that Rav J.B. Soloveitchik used one sink without a rack while his wife was away, and the next day taught his class how.  I cannot prove this however.  I believe it simply involved cold water and soap.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen, yes, if there's no heat involved (you use only cold water), then there should be no problem. I can understand why he didn't do this when his wife was at home.

Comment: Related, especially to these comments: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22321.

Comment: @YDK Davar gush

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever makes the most sense for you and your kitchen.

Comment: ... and your wife

Comment: ...or rather, both of you. (You will both be washing dishes rather than expecting her to do all of them, right?)

Comment: Alex, Gut Voch!  Good husband!  I've heard washing the dishes is a segulah for shalom bayis!

Comment: @Shalom Story with the Lubavitcher Rebbe: A man once asked the Lubavitcher Rebbe if it is true that folding your tallis right after shabbos is a segulah for shalom bayis. The Rebbe answered, "I don't know about that, but rolling up your sleeves and doing the dishes after shabbos is a segulah for shalom bayis".

Answer (score 2):

Often times people make the Fleishige side the side closer to the oven - for practical reasons, as that is what is cooked most, however everyone can and should do what makes most sense for them.