# How does one keep a kosher sink?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, appliances

How does one keep a sink kosher when using two separate sets of plates and dishes?

Comment: as a practical question, I would recommend sitting with your LOR for guidance. Dish racks, basins etc are often alternatives but the exact way to do each and what is considered acceptable within each community needs to be discussed with a local expert.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3350. (See also comments on that question.)

Comment: Use soap and cold water.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ok.org/Content.asp?ID=115

> The Sink: Separate sinks for washing dishes and preparing foods are
>   recommended. If the two sinks are adjoining, there should be an
>   effective separation between them so that no water or food splashes
>   from one sink to the other.
>
> If there is only one sink, it may be used after it has been completely
>   cleaned, but the inside of the sink should be regarded as non-kosher.
>   No food or dishes should be put directly into non-kosher sinks. There
>   should be separate dish pans and slightly elevated racks under the
>   dish pans for both meat and dairy. Similarly, two sinks which were
>   used before the kitchen was kosher should also be regarded as
>   non-kosher, unless they are stainless steel and were koshered. If the
>   two sinks were koshered, one should be designated for meat and one for
>   dairy.