# Shalom Bayis story to share at a Chuppah speech

Tags: marriage, family-members, wedding, speeches-addresses

I am supposed to give a speech on a chuppah next week BSD.

I am totally blank! Have had a few ideas to talk about, focusing on Shalom Bayit, but I cannot pick a nice one so everyone present can learn from it.

Would anyone have any good and inspiring Shalom Bayis stories to share so I could pick one?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/325167/jewish/The-Shalom-Bayit-Kugel.htm

Comment: I wish I could remember the whole story and which gadol it was,but the way I remember it was that a bachur was getting married and he was going to his Rebbi who was giving him chosson classes and when he got there his rebbi took out a pot and filled it with water and said are you watching carefully.The bachur watched very carefully as his rebbi proceeded.His rebbi than took rice out and put it in the boiling water and waited to it was cooked and so on...The bachur astonished asked I thought we were gonna learn the halachos of marriage?The rebbi answered this exactly what I am teaching you,one

Comment: Day your wife might not be feeling well and who is going to make dinner,I am showing you practically how to do it yourself.This is a very powerful message of shalom bayis.

Comment: [The kerosene-in-the-chulent story.](http://www.artscroll.com/Chapters/sg5h-001.html)

Answer (score 5):

I once posted this [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/milchig-fleishig-arrangement#comment10153_3351):

> Story with the Lubavitcher Rebbe: A man once asked the Lubavitcher Rebbe if it is true that folding your tallis right after shabbos is a segulah for shalom bayis. The Rebbe answered, "I don't know about that, but rolling up your sleeves and doing the dishes after shabbos is a segulah for shalom bayis".

Answer (score 4):

Or this story from [here](http://learningtogive.org/faithgroups/voices/shalom_bayit.asp)

> It is important not to fall prey to the danger of forfeiting Shalom
>   Bayit in the very process of pursuing the ideal of a blissful Jewish
>   home. The story is told that one Friday night the Chafetz Chaim
>   visited the home of a man who berated his wife for not remembering to
>   cover the challot before the recitation of Kiddush, causing her to
>   leave the table in tears. The Chofetz Chaim, in addressing this
>   uncomfortable situation, was able to use his wisdom to give the
>   intemperate husband a sense of perspective. Drawing from Jewish law
>   sources, he pointed out to the man that one reason that we cover the
>   challot is to shield the challot from the “embarrassment” of not
>   receiving the first brocha of the meal. Accordingly, asked the Chafetz
>   Chaim, how could Kiddush be recited when the man's own wife had been
>   embarrassed? The man immediately understood the error of his ways and
>   begged his wife for forgiveness. The importance of sensitive
>   communications in the frantic frenzy of Shabbat preparations is an
>   obvious application of this principle.

Comment: ....I thought this would end, "and so the man covered his wife."

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Gold

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhuCWb0TV9U) is my favorite collection of ideas to share at a chuppah (told over by Rabbi Shlomo Carlebach).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, @Roman! I hope you'll stick around to learn and contribute to the site. I see you've already registered an account, which is a great way to access more features as your reputation grows. Consider taking this short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. For general help see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Is that a collection of *shalom bayit* stories?  Can you summarize it?